# Is there a way to generate a public key on postman pre request script using the x.509 spec

Tags: javascript, postman

I have my public key encoded in base64 string and I want to generate the public key from that on postman pre request script. I am able to do this using kotlin on the code level. But this time I want to do it on javascript because thats what postman uses in script.

Here is my code on my kotlin

```
fun loadPublicKey(key64: String): PublicKey? {
    val data: ByteArray = BaseEncoding.base64().decode(key64)
    val spec = X509EncodedKeySpec(data)
    val fact = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA")
    return fact.generatePublic(spec)
}
```

Thanks in advance